# How to check if user enters blank line in scanf

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf

I need the program to exit the while loop if the user presses enter without entering any float value.

```c
printf("Enter scores\n");

float scores[10];
int n=0;    

while (n < 10){
    scanf("%f", &scores[n]);
    n++;
    if (THE USER PRESSES ENTER WITHOUT ENTERING ANYTHING)
        break;
}
```

Comment: You will have to avoid `scanf()` when you start coding real things.

Comment: I would give a try to gets()

Comment: @mosh442: absolutely not `gets()`!  SO is a healthy living site and using `gets()` is about as unhealthy as it gets.  Now, `fgets()` would be a different matter altogether.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `fgets()` to read a line of input through the newline character into a buffer, and then use `sscanf()` to parse the contents of the buffer. The problem with using `scanf()` for this is that most conversion specifiers, and in particular the `%f` conversion specifier, skip leading whitespace, including newlines. So, if you try to give an empty line to `scanf()`, the function will continue to wait for input until you enter a non-white-space character.

The code below adapts this technique to your code. The variable `n` has been changed to a `size_t` type variable, as this is an unsigned type guaranteed to be able to hold any array index. Furthermore, note that both `fgets()` and `sscanf()` return values that should be checked. The `fgets()` function returns a null pointer if there is an error, and the code below prints an error message and exits if this occurs. The `sscanf()` function returns the number of successful conversions made, and this value can be used to make sure that the input is as expected. When the user enters a blank line, or a line with no leading floating point value (leading white-space is OK), zero is returned, and the input loop is escaped.

I added some code to display the values entered into the array.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>                 // for exit()

int main(void)
{
    float scores[10];
    char buffer[100];
    size_t n = 0;

    printf("Enter scores\n");

    while (n < 10){
        if (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin) == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error in fgets()\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        if (sscanf(buffer, "%f", &scores[n]) == 1) {
            ++n;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("scores[%zu] = %f\n", i, scores[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Sample interaction:

```
Enter scores
3.8
3.6
2.9
3.4

scores[0] = 3.800000
scores[1] = 3.600000
scores[2] = 2.900000
scores[3] = 3.400000
```

Answer (score 2):

Separate input of user text from parsing.
Read the *line* of user input as a string;

```
char buffer[80];
if (fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, stdin) == NULL) Handle_EOF();
```

*Now*, parse the string using `sscanf()`, `strtod()`, etc.

```
if (sscanf(buffer, "%f", &scores[n]) == 1) Handle_Successful_Float_Input(scores[n]);
else if (buffer[0] == '\n') Handle_Empty_Line();
else Handle_Everything_Else(buffer);
```

Answer (score 0):

`fgets` is the better route but if scanf must be used, newline can be detected by scanning a character. If the character is not a newline, replace it in the input with `ungetc` and then scan the float.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define SIZE 10

int main ( void) {
    char i = '\0';
    int n = 0;
    int result = 0;
    float scores[SIZE] = { 0.0f};

    printf ( "enter scores\n");
    while ( n < SIZE && ( scanf("%c",&i) == 1)) {//scan a character
        if ( i == '\n') {
            break;//newline so leave loop
        }
        else {
            ungetc ( i, stdin);//replace the character in input stream
        }
        if ( ( result = scanf ( "%f", &scores[n])) == 1) {//scan a float
            printf ( " score[%d] entered as %f\n", n, scores[n]);
            n++;
        }
        if ( result == 0) {
            printf ( "please enter a number\n");//could not scan the input as a float
        }
        while ( ( result = getchar ( )) != '\n') {//clean the input stream
            if ( result == EOF) {
                fprintf ( stderr, "problem EOF\n");
                return 1;
            }
        }
        printf ( "enter score[%d]\n", n);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I thought . you want to check that if an integer is assigned a value or not ?
Actually you have to initialize the variable otherwise it will contain whatever happen at that memory location unless it is declared as global. If you are not getting then check 
[this might help you with your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1226489/c-check-if-integer-is-assigned)

Comment: The code is reading floating point numbers, not integers.  I think you've missed the point of the question — which is about detecting when a blank line is entered while using the `scanf()` family of functions.

Answer (score -2):

We know that scanf returns a negative value if nothing of the defined type is fetched from the input.

So:

```
printf("Enter scores\n”);

float scores[10];
int n=0;    

while (n<10){

    if(scanf("%f\n", &scores[n]) < 0) printf("Error! Error!");

    n++;
}
```

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/

Comment: But it doesn't stop looking just because it sees a newline.

Comment: `scanf()` returns `EOF` only if end-of-file is reached before any matches are made. But, `scanf()` returns when the first non-match is encountered, or end-of-file is reached. So, 0 is returned if no conversions are made, unless eof is reached. You should test `scanf() != 1`. And, the `%f` conversion skips leading whitespace, including newlines, anyway.

Comment: @AlexFang-- that won't work. This is one of the subtleties of `scanf()`. If you put a white-space character at the end of a format string, `scanf()` will continue greedily asking for more input until a non-white-space character is encountered (or `EOF` is reached). The result is that input blocks until the user enters a non-white-space character or signals `EOF` from the keyboard. See [§7.21.6.2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2) of the C11 Draft Standard, in particular [paragraph 5](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.2p5).

Comment: BTW, not a downvoter, I was just trying to point out that `scanf()` does _not_ necessarily return "a negative value if nothing of the defined type is fetched from the input." Your test should be `!= 1` instead of `< 0`. But, even at that, `scanf()` will not read an empty line here, since the `%f` conversion skips over leading white-space.