# C while loop does not stop running once input is made

Tags: c

I am trying to create a program that repeatedly asks the user for input. However, in this case, the program just keeps printing `"Enter your input"` until it crashes after I enter something for the first time.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    while (1) {
        char input[100];

        printf("Enter a input: ");
        scanf("%[^\n]s", input);
    }
}
```

Comment: If you check the return value from `scanf`, you'll see that it's not reading anything, which could be a good clue.

Comment: Note that you almost certainly meant `"%[^\n]"` instead of `"%[^\n]s"`, unless you really want to match a literal `s` in the input.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Read a string as an input using scanf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35103745/read-a-string-as-an-input-using-scanf)

Comment: This may also be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42265038/how-to-check-if-user-enters-blank-line-in-scanf-in-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In:

```
scanf("%[^\n]s", input);
```

There are 2 problems:

1. The `s` is not part of that specific specifier, it should be only `%[^\n]`.
2. That specifier leaves the `\n` newline character in the input buffer.

   Your cycle will enter an infinite loop because there is always something to read there, but it's something that must not be parsed and should remain in the buffer.

   A simple way to get rid of it is to place a space before the specifier:

   ```
   scanf(" %[^\n]", input);
          ^
          |
   ```

Answer (score 1):

You are asking `scanf()` to read everything up to, *but not including*, the line break that ends the user's input.

So, the line break stays in the input buffer. Then on subsequent calls to `scanf()`, the line break is still not read from the input buffer, preventing `scanf()` from reading any new input.

You need to read that line break from the input buffer so that a subsequent call to `scanf()` can read the user's next input.